# Is it possible to trigger a notification on Android from outside the JVM?

Tags: android, go, jvm, ipc

I know Go pretty well but I don't know Java or anything about Android. I have compiled a Go program and run it via command line on Android and ideally I would like to run it in the background and have it send me a notification using the official notification system without  using a third party app.

Is this possible? Could it be done with some type of inter process communication?